# Connection to DB2400 Database from Netbeans

Tags: java, database, persistence, ibm-midrange, netbeans-8

I want to create a Persistence Unit in Netbeans, but I can't connect the drivers with a DB2/400 Database. I don't now if something was wrong on AS400 (IBM I) or I'm doing something wrong. I was using 2 drivers to try to connect to the database, but no one works.

These are the error messages:

**Using the first driver (db2jcc.jar WITH db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar)**

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:db2://HOST:446/DATABASE using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver ([jcc][t4][2057][11264][3.69.24] The application server rejected establishment of the connection.  An attempt was made to access a database, DATABASE, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004)

**Using the second Driver (db2jcc4.jar WITH db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar)**

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:db2://HOST:446/DATABASE using com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver ([jcc][t4][2057][11264][3.69.24] The application server rejected establishment of the connection.  An attempt was made to access a database, DATABASE, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the "DATABASE" name is correct? I get the same error when 
the "DATABASE" not is not correct.

*An attempt was made to access a database, GARBAGE, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004*

The "DATABASE" name should be the *LOCAL entry seen in WRKRDBDIRE. If you use *LOCAL as the DATABASE name, that should also work.

For connecting to IBM i, an alternative JDBC driver is JTOpen JDBC driver (http://jt400.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: DATABASE is a incorrect database name,  I replace it with the correct name in my connection.